# How to make this css based menu open and close on click instead of open on hover and close on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

The working version of the css menu is here http://jsfiddle.net/nexU/PEvrW/1/ and it works on all browsers and after changing hover to click, menu has to continue working on all browsers too.

Complete menu markup on jsfiddle

```
.menu ul li a:hover {background:#fff; color:#000;}
```

As you can see all I need is to make the menu open on click, and close on click, so that when user selects a tab by one click, the tab remains open unless another tab is selected by click, or the same tab is reclicked to close it.. I already tried JQuery, but could not get it to work, and looked another posts but the tips did not work either. In other words menu has to work like this bootstrap menu which is activated on clicks: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Post your jQuery attempt.

Comment: Why did you choose a CSS meny with hover effects if you wanted something completely different ?

Comment: jQuery has a menu plugin: [jQuery UI Menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/)

Comment: I don't want something completely different. I want that exact menu to work with clicks instead of hovers. The hover functionality is not working well, so that's why I need to replace the hover for clicks to open and close the menu. I tried using hoverIntent jquery plug-in, and jquery toggle as mentioned on other similar posts, but perhaps I'm not using it correctly because  when I remove the hovers, and put the toggle and jquery, the menu no longer works. ie: $("a").click(function(e){
   $(this).closest("li").children("ul").toggle();
});
$("a").click();

Comment: This question has nothing to do with CSS selectors. Please don't put the tag back in.

Comment: @Stano. Thank you :) . your solution is almost done, but when you click on A tab while B tab is already open, the A tab does not close and remains open. very close. Thanks.

Comment: @Stano. Thanks for your time and help. :) your version 17 is pretty much what I want, but if you replace the # for actual links <li><a href="index.html">Link 1</a></li> the links no longer work, not sure why. you should have posted your comments as answer, so that I can select it as answer, it is the most helpful of all (only part left is making the links work, since not sure what the toggling will add to the menu, what you did with open and closing the tabs is working great).

Comment: @Stano In other words with v17 open and close works great, except when clicking on the links of the other tabs (Link 1, Link2 etc..). When you click on those links, to clicks are closing the menu too, instead of linking to an actual page which is the correct behavior. (When clicking on Tab #0 is not going to index.html. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks nexU, here is that corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PEvrW/18/ That jQuery's toggle() method only toggles element's .css.display property, so i modified your css menu, so now it doesn't move the ul-tag to the outside of window. Thanks, i won't add this as an answer, you can accept anybody else's answer, you consider the most useful. (also deleted my previous comments here) (cleaned)

Comment: @Stano, thanks a lot. v18 works great. all links work except the Tab #0 which does not have submenu and is going to link to Home page. I can not accept any other answers, as the most useful and helpful as of now, is your answer, you took from your own time to make the menu work. I appreciate your help :). If you add v18 as an answer, I'll accept yours.

Comment: Still the script is not fully functional and should be modified accordingly to it also the css. If a page visitor has javascript disabled on his/her pc, then the menu won't be shown. Personally I'd better don't use javascript for toggling menus (otherwise is js great).

Comment: Personally i'd accept Dave's answer, but do what you think is right. Maybe somebody can give you a better answer here. Have a nice day nexU :)

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try to do toggle with some of the tips from this site: http://www.joesnellpdx.com/toggle-navigation-no-javascript/ Thanks and have a great day too :)

Answer (score 2):

`:hover` is a css class that you can use to change the appearance of things on... hover.

On order to "Click and do stuff" (even if it's basically changing the state/appearance of something, similar to that hover) use Javascript.  So you'd need to add javascript and possibly jquery.

jQuery might be something like

```
$('a').click(function() {this.background='#fff'; this.color='#000'})
```

maybe show/hide with `.slideDown.toggle` or the like.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I also read on a post that to do the click functionality it needs js / jquery. I tried toggle with jquery, in different ways but it is not working: ie: $("a").click(function(e){ $(this).closest("li").children("ul").toggle(); }); $("a").click();

Comment: Sure, first thing you need is to get your browser tools going and be able to see the javascript errors, then post what those are.  Firefox and Chrome are both good for that.  Chrome is many developers favorite these days.

Comment: `.hover` is not a CSS state, its a class. Did you mean `:hover` ?

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen at http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/cssplay-click-drop-fly.html, a pure CSS menu can work and is actually fairly easy to do, just use the `:active` pseudo-class.

Here is the basic structure of all CSS menus with the appropriate CSS selectors.

NOTE: there are many ways to structure the HTML, I chose these tags as they are unambiguous in the below css selectors. Almost any structure of this form works.

```
<menu>
    <div>
        <a href="#non-existant-tag-to-avoid-jumping-to-it">Tab #1</a>
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
    </div>
    ...
</menu>
```

And the CSS selectors:

```
menu > div > li {
    /* rules to hide it */
}
menu > div > a:active + li, /* clicked */
menu > div:hover > li { /* hovered */
    /* rules to show it */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its Simple Just Make Change In Your Script.
wherever you have used

### onmouseover

change it to

### onclick

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but if you look at the actual menu at http://jsfiddle.net/nexU/PEvrW/1/ you'll find that the whole menu is css based, there is no script, and that's why I posted the question. To make menu work with clicks js or jquery will need to be added.